# Chart creation in BIDS 2008

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, business-intelligence

Due to low reputation point i am not able to include the picture.

I am trying to make u guys understand what i am asking for:

I had created a report. And that Report contains these fields and values:

```
  Name, YTDPlan, Actual, YearPlan
  Rev ,  4418  ,  4410 ,  24069
```

I have included the first row of this report, for that i have to create a line graph. Can anyone please tell me what fields should be taken on which axis.?

Comment: Only *you* (or your client) can decide what dimension you want on which axis (though date/time values are usually on the x-axis). In any case: why not try the various options and see what gives you the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on what you want your graph to show (i.e. trending, inconsistencies, over time, over categories, etc.).  Some additional context would be helpful.

Looking at what you provided my first thought would be to show the data trending over time where one line represents "Actual" and the other "YTDPlan".  This would show an "actual vs. plan" comparison.  Using this assumption as an example, I would plot these 2 fields on the x-axis.  You can limit what you show over time in your query or a report parameter.  SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) will auto-create the values for you for the y-axis once the report is run (SSRS does this by analyzing the min and max bound values of your x-axis data).