# Data from two table in SQL server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have 2 tables:

Codes table with following column:

```
                         Name, Code
```

History table with following column:

```
                         Name, BU, Plan.
```

Now, I want code column of Codes table in place of Name column of History table.

I.e History table should contain Code, BU, Plan.

Here how can i achieve this?

Comment: Does either table have a primary key? What is it? What does `SELECT KPI, COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Codes GROUP BY KPI` return? How about `SELECT KPI, COUNT(*) FROM dbo.History GROUP BY KPI`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `Code` is a `VARCHAR(32)` (just change the first line if my assumption is incorrect):

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.History ADD Code VARCHAR(32);

UPDATE h
  SET Code = c.Code
  FROM dbo.History AS h
  INNER JOIN dbo.Codes AS c
  ON h.Name = c.Name;

-- verify first, then:

ALTER TABLE dbo.History DROP COLUMN Name;
```

If you absolutely need the columns to be in the same order (you shouldn't), you can rebuild the table as follows:

```
-- first, drop all constraints that point to dbo.History. Then:

SELECT Code, BU, Plan 
  INTO dbo.HistoryCopy
  FROM dbo.History;

EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.History', 'dbo.HistoryOld', 'OBJECT';
EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.HistoryCopy', 'dbo.History', 'OBJECT';

-- now re-create the constraints / indexes etc. on the new copy
```

In order to prevent user activity from affecting or being affected, you'll want to do this during a maintenance window, or surround the above with a serializable transaction.

When you're happy that the change is successful, you can drop the old copy:

```
DROP TABLE dbo.HistoryOld;
```

Comment: Yepp, Code is NVARCHAR(Max), which is just a short code for Name column of History Table. 

When i tried this code it was giving me 3 times the original row. Lets say i should have 30 rows but after execution of this it was giving me 90 rows as answer..

Comment: Then it sounds like Name is not unique. Please describe the schema of the tables *including keys* and maybe some sample data / how you want it to look when the change is complete. Otherwise we're guessing. Also, why are you using NVARCHAR(MAX) for a "short" code?

Comment: Yeah name is not unique, I have attached the image may b it will help u a abit to understand my problem.

Schema is dbo, And i havnt specified any key.

Sorry i am new on SQL server so may be i will not be able to answer properly. Apologies.

Comment: Without seeing the duplicates I don't understand how you ended up with 90 rows instead of 30. If you don't absolutely need the column order to be the same, then just execute the first portion.

Comment: Now can you please help me with my another Query. 

http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15451/chart-creation-in-bids-2008

Comment: Sorry, I am not a BIDS guy.